# How to zip file to a folder doesn't exist with bash script linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to zip a folder to a directory which does not exist. Similar as

```
zip -r /home/unExistFolder/test.zip /home/logFolder
```

If there's no such folder, then create folder. If there's folder, just put into it.

How can I realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 newDir="/path/with spaces/to/archive"

 if ! [[ -d "$newDir" ]] ; then
     mkdir -p "$newDir"
 fi
 zip  -r /home/unExistFolder/test.zip "$newDir"
```

Some versions of zip may offer an "I'll make the directory if it doesn't exist" feature/option, but if you want something that will always work, this is your best bet.

I've made `newDir` equal to "/path/with spaces/to/archive" to remind you that if you don't dbl-quote your usage of variables, you'll get mysterious error messages. While there are a few occasions where you don't want to dbl-quote a variable, usually you should dbl-quote all variable usage in shell scripting.

IHTH